# why do we put using before streamreader in c#

Tags: c#, .net, using

why do we put using before `streamreader` in `c#`

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt")) 
{
    string line;
    // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
    // the file is reached.
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Putting your cursor on the keyword and pressing `F1` would have told you what you needed to know...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

using block in C# comes very handly while dealing with disposable  objects. Disposable objects are those objects that can explicitly release the resources they use when called to dispose. As we know .Net garbage collection is non-deterministic so you can’t predict when exactly the object will be garbage collected.

Read this post for more in details : [understanding ‘using’ block in C#](http://www.ruchitsurati.net/index.php/2010/07/28/understanding-%E2%80%98using%E2%80%99-block-in-c/)

Comment: Rather than quoting a blog post (copying and pasting even) and then just pointing to the post, you should elaborate a little further and talk about why releasing resources is important; i.e. the role `using` and `IDispose` play in the releasing of **unmanaged** resources.

Answer (score 6):

So that when you are done using `StreamReader` it is disposed of properly. Also, in the event of an exception, the `using` statement calls `Dispose` before the exception propagates out.

Answer (score 6):

Its good practice to use the `using` syntax whenever you are working with an object that implements `IDisposable`, (which `StreamReader` does) as it ensures that the `Dispose` method always gets called and the object is properly disposed of.

For example in this case various handles / locks will be obtained on the file "*TestFile.txt*" that may prevent others from writing to or even reading this file until either the stream reader is disposed of or the process ends.  Other objects (such as database objects) may use up database connections or network resources and so you should always dispose of objects as soon as you are done using them - the using statement is simply an easy and safe pattern to follow when doing this.

Under the covers whats happening is similar to this ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)):

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt");
try
{
    string line;
    // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
    // the file is reached.
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
finally
{
    if (sr != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)sr).Dispose();
    }
}
```

However the using statement is much cleaner (and less error prone) than attempting to dispose of the `IDisposable` by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Without `using` the file would not be closed when it was finished with.

Answer (score 3):

The code is translated by the compiler to:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt")
try
{
    string line;
    // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
    // the file is reached.
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
finally
{
    sr.Dispose();
}
```

This ensures that whatever happens, `sr` is properly disposed (cleaned up). Whenever an object is created that implements the `IDisposable` interface it is best practice to wrap it in a `using` construct to ensure it is cleaned up and releases any expensive or scarce resources as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it is important that we `Dispose` of objects after we have finished with them.

Wrapping the construction of an object in a `using` block means that the disposal is handled automatically as soon the code within the braces is completed.

In the case of a `StreamReader` reading a text file, this is important as the file is locked by the system while the StreamReader is reading it. Releasing the lock allows other processes to modify or delete the file.

Answer (score 3):

`using` statement guaranteed that `Dispose()` method will be called, and `Dispose()` calls `stream.Close()`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use using, but it is a convenient way of being absolutely sure that the object is properly disposed of. You can do this without using, as long as you are certain that you always dispose of the object at the end ( `using` a finally is the normal way ). If there are specific reasons for wanting to persist the object further you can do this.

However, there is probaly something with your code structure if you are trying to do this. Encasing your use of `StreamReader` ( and other `iDisposible` objects ) in a `using` statement helps to structure your code well.

Comment: You do need to use `using` (or call `Dispose` explicitly) if you want control over when the file is closed.

Comment: Yes absolutely. You do not have to in terms of compilation, but you must to avoid major problems with the file system.